# In C programming make a Do-While loop to ask user if they want the program to run again

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

This program so far sweeps through the frequency range 0-20000 Hz and prints every 50 Hz on screen, it then stops when it reaches 20000 Hz. It also stops if I move a control on an on screen midi keyboard.

Now what I'm trying to do is to modify it so that when it has reached 2000 Hz, instead of stopping, the program gives the user an option, something like "Do you want to start this program again?", and if the user types 'Y' then it will start again, but if the user types 'N' the program will stop. I believe a `do while` is what I'm looking for, but I've tried and just can't seem to get it to work.

My Code:

```
#include "aservelibs/aservelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int frequency = 0.0;
    int modulation = aserveGetControl(1);

    printf("aserve get note control is %d\n", modulation);

    do
    {
        while( frequency < 20000.0 && modulation == 0)
        {
            modulation = aserveGetControl(1);
            aserveOscillator(0,frequency,1.0,0);
            printf("The frequency is: %dHz\n", frequency);
            frequency = frequency + 50.0;
            aserveSleep(20);
        }

        char userInput;
        printf("enter 'y' if you would like to repeat: ");
        scanf(" %c", &userInput);
        while(userInput == 'y');
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You havent included the portion where you collect input and return Y/N .. and try the loop..to be honest what you do in the loop is basically irrelevant.

Comment: yeah ive removed that because it just wasnt functioning at all, the question is asking how I can do that.

Comment: Well, you have a while loop already, so you have the basics of a while loop - it would be easier to start with your not really working loop and fix..

Comment: I guess maybe a better question is, is it possible for me to have a while loop within a do while loop?

Comment: Thats what ive been trying to do anyway

Comment: yes you can have loops within loops within other types of loops

Comment: Hi BugFinder, I've edited the code in this post to show what ive been attempting to do, any help would be appreciated, apologies for not being very clear at the start

Comment: I changed formatting - but did not change anything else (syntax errors!) to get the code more readable.

Comment: Your problem is simple .. and a common mistake.  "while(userInput == 'y');"  so this will basically hang your machine if you press y.. you need to move it to the outside of that } below, and it should work

Comment: It stops at 20000 Hz *and* if a control is moved, but you only ask for restart at 20000 Hz - intended or do you want to restart after both stop conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your concept is correct, but you have just missed the syntax of `do while` loop.

It should be

```
do {

} while(condition);
```

So, modified code will be

```
#include "aservelibs/aservelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int frequency = 0.0;
    int modulation = aserveGetControl(1);
    printf("aserve get note control is %d\n", modulation);
    char userInput;

    do
    {
        while( frequency < 20000.0 && modulation == 0)
        {
            modulation = aserveGetControl(1);
            aserveOscillator(0,frequency,1.0,0);
            printf("The frequency is: %dHz\n", frequency);
            frequency = frequency + 50.0;
            aserveSleep(20);
        }

        printf("enter 'y' if you would like to repeat:  ");
        scanf(" %c", &userInput);
    } while(userInput == 'y');

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At very first, you have a syntax error: The `while` clause has to be placed outside of the loop body:

```cpp
do
{
}
while(someCondition); // here!
```

Variables defined inside the loop body are not accessible outside of it - so you need to declare them before:

```cpp
char userInput;
do
{
}
while(userInput == 'y');
```

Apart from that, your code should work fine.

Comment: thanks alot for your help! that worked but it is only asking before the loop starts and not after the value of frequency is greater than 20000. So im trying to make it that it asks afterwards so the user has the option of hearing the sweep again.

Comment: @ArchieWillis Perhaps reset the value of `frequency` and `modulation`?

Comment: yes that worked!! thanks so much!! and everyone else for your help!